# ROR + find_or_initialize_by_id Method Functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In Model, I am using `"find_or_initialize"` to save an record. I assume that this function will search the record in the database, if it found then no action and if did not find then save the record. Am I correct or not ?

But, confusion : If the record is already exists, and one of the field get updated then will this function update the record or not ?

```
Is there any other method to resolve it ?
```

Please suggest me to resolve this issue... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`find_or_initialize_by_...` won't ever save the record it will only instantiate a new object with the provided parameters set.

If you want the record to be saved automatically (if it's not found) then you should be using `find_or_create_by_...` instead.

In either case, any changes you make to the object will have to be followed by a `save` if you want them saved to the database. Neither of these methods will save anything you do after it's called.

Comment: Thnx for the response. Is there any way to update by same function. Like find_or_initialize_or_update something ?

Comment: I don't think so. How would you even want it to work? Would you have one set of parameters for finding and the other for updating? That could make sense for a `find_or_create_or_update_by` method I suppose but it's not something that's supported out of the box in Rails.